# When to use of 买

Tags: verbs

I teacher mine told me that 买 could be use to buy/purchase but also to "to decide to buy", or "go shopping", other teacher told me the first one was wrong.

Who is right?

Comment: The first teacher is a woman, the second teacher is a man. ;)

Comment: Without further context and explanation, the first one is wrong.

Comment: "decide to buy" is 决定买, which means you just make a decision, but have not bought

Comment: Probably the first teacher told you that because when you see 买到 in the future she'll remember you that 买 is the attempt to buy, while 买到 is buying indeed.

Answer (score 1):

买 means "to buy". But the phrase 买东西 means "to go shopping". You can use similar phrases like 买衣服, 买蔬菜 and so on to mean "shop for clothes / vegetables". You could say:

> 我买东西去了，可是商店关门了，没有买到。
>   I went shopping, but the store was closed, so I didn't buy anything.

There could be a similar context where it means "decide to buy", but I haven't heard it used in that sense.

Your second teacher is right in that it normally does only mean "to buy".

Comment: Decide to buy: 买不买？买。

Answer (score -1):

I am Chinese student.
买 could be use to buy/purchase but also to "to decide to buy", or "go shopping"
买and卖：buy and sell